# Splitting Spark stream by delimiter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to split my Spark stream based on a delimiter and save each of these chunks to a new file.

Each of my RDDs appear to be partitioned according to the delimiter.

I am having difficulty in configuring one delimiter message per RDD, or, being able to save each partition individually to a new `part-000...` file .

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
 val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DataSink").setMaster("local[8]").set("spark.files.overwrite","false")
 val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))

 class RouteConsumer extends Actor with ActorHelper with Consumer {
    def endpointUri = "rabbitmq://server:5672/myexc?declare=false&queue=in_hl7_q"
    def receive = {
        case msg: CamelMessage =>
           val m = msg.withBodyAs[String]
           store(m.body)
     }
 }

 val dstream = ssc.actorStream[String](Props(new RouteConsumer()), "SparkReceiverActor")
 val splitStream = dstream.flatMap(_.split("MSH|^~\\&"))
 splitStream.foreachRDD( rdd => rdd.saveAsTextFile("file:///home/user/spark/data") )

 ssc.start()
 ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't control which `part-NNNNN` (partition) file gets which output, but you can write to different directories. The "easiest" way to do this sort of column splitting is with separate map statements (like `SELECT` statements), something like this, assuming you'll have `n` array elements after splitting:

`...
val dstream2 = dstream.map(_.split("..."))  // like above, but with map
dstream2.cache()  // very important for what follows, repeated reads of this...
val dstreams = new Array[DStream[String]](n)
for (i <- 0 to n-1) {
  dstreams[i] = dstream2.map(array => array[i] /* or similar */)
  dstreams[i].saveAsTextFiles(rootDir+"/"+i)
}
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure I understnad what the map in the first line of the for loop would do. Could you please explain? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I changed to much of your example. It's the line `val splitStream = dstream.flatMap(_.split("MSH|^~\\&"))`. Rather than returning a separate record for each substring extracted, it returns the whole array for each record as a new record so that the subsequent `map` calls just project out the array elements you want.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please update your answer as I am still strguglling to understand